# Can I identify which routed event from the triggers that caused the property change from code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, propertychanged

I have the below style trigger in the XAML, changing property based on a routed event which works properly.

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ThumbnailItemBackgroundSelected}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ThumbnailItemBorderSelected}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ThumbnailItemBackgroundMouseHover}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ThumbnailItemBorderMouseHover}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

I would like to get which event that caused the property change in `OnPropertyChanged`, but I didn't get the details about it in the override event.

```
 protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.Property.Name == "Background") {}
 }
```

Can I Identify which routed event (MouseDown or MouseEnter) that caused the property change (ex. Background) from code in any way?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you need this information? Maybe there is a better solution without checking the event names.

Comment: Based on the changes in Property with respect to the event, I would like updating other element. Since the same property is changing twice on different events, it does not meet my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You might not get MouseEnter and MouseDown events using OnPropertyChanged. You should use MouseEnter and MouseDown events respectively and call your code inside these Events respectively.
Like this : Below Input => is a TextBox

```
private void Input_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
Input.Text = "Mouse Entered";}

private void Input_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
Input.Text = "Mouse Left";}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. However it will not meet my requirement as mentioned in my previous comments.